# How can I share a token variable from my main page to iframe other than using a post message?

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

I need to know how to share a variable in parent window to iframe. 
My scenario is this, 
I have **2 angular5 application** say **A** and **B** .
B is loaded as an Iframe to A.
Authentication is done in A and I get an access token which i need to pass to B.
These are the things I tried.

1. postMessage sent the token but as it is async event, B doesn't wait for it.
2. Tried passing token as a header by making an AJAX get request with response type 
   as blob but failed as only the index file is loaded not the angular chunks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use open B iframe with the auth token as the query param:

```
<iframe src="yourURL?auth_token=ASDF1234"></iframe>
```

Comment: Isn't this insecure?